# Raid 0 with Sata 3 and MSata SSDs

Tags: windows-8, ssd, lenovo-laptop, raid-0, msata

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 laptop, which has an MSata slot for MSata SSDs. The laptop came with a Seagate 5400 RPM 1TB HDD which I put in an external enclosure and installed an AData SP 900 Pro SSD in its place. I'm planing on buying an MSata SSD as soon as I see a good offer.

My question is: can I do RAID 0 with my normal SSD and my MSata SSD? Has anyone tried this ?

Also, what would the procedure be if I don't want to lose any data currently on my SSD? I own a license of Acronis True Image, if that's of any help.

Comment: You want to build a RAID 0 setup with a drive contained within a external. What connection does this enclosure use exactly? The procedure would be to duplicate the drive you want to save, setup the raid, then restore the image to the raid.  You should verify your copy of Acronis True Image supports a RAID setup.

Comment: I read it as 'the HDD was removed and I use two SSDs instead'.  (The HDD did not even have to get mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for the info about duplicating the drive, I'll look into it. I did say that my laptop came with an HDD, I removed the HDD and put it in an USB 3 external enclosure, and the I put an SSD in the laptop to replace the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the exact same drives for balanced RAID0 I/O.
RAID0 does put data at risk since the data is spread over 2 disks.
Probably best to use 2 mSATA or 2 SSD of same model together and do daily backups to your external 500GB disk.

I have an ACER Aspire S5 391 with dual mSATA, I/O is +700Mb/s with Crystal Disk Mark (i5-3317). My Desktop with an ADATA 256 SSD is +500 Mb/s (i7-3770k). The RAID0 is definitely faster.